# Specify floating point number accuracy in NSString

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, nsstring, string-formatting

I'm trying to specify the accuracy of my floating pointer number in my NSString but I keep on getting this error:

> Format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'NSString *'

Here is my code:

```
NSString *tmplabel = [tmp description];
temp.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat: @"%.fº", tmplabel];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tmplabel is an object of NSString. so, you can not use %f. use %@ for object of NSString

Comment: what you want in output?

Comment: @DharaParekh Thanks for your comment, but if I use %@ then I can't control the accuracy of the floating point number. Basically, the number currently comes out as 8.xx I want it to be 8.x so I need to use %f??

Comment: so that I ask you for your expected o/p. see my answer for you desired output...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tmplabel is an `NSString`, it should be a `double`.

If you are sure tmplabel holds a number that can be parsed as a simple double, then you can just use `doubleValue` on it. Otherwise you might have to do a more elaborate conversion with error handling etc.

Here's a down-to-Earth simple way to do it:

```
temp.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat: @"%.fº", [tmplabel doubleValue]];
```

The `doubleValue` method (and its close relatives `integerValue`, and similar) *interprets* the string's content and if the beginning of the string can be read as a number, it will convert it for you and return it as the appropriate primitive type. In your case the primitive type is `double`.

You can not make a type cast from an object (anything NS*) to a primitive type, but always have to go through some sort of interpretation or programmatic conversion.

Last, please notice that using `doubleValue` directly on user input is a shortcut that you will want to re-visit at some point, so make a mental note of re-implementing it using a either a number formatter or `NSScanner` later. To get an idea why, try to enter non-numerical data and see if you are happy with the result.

Finally, to actually set the accuracy (i.e., number of decimals after the decimal point) as you asked for, see either prince's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16543049/644348) below, or [DharaParekh's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16541785/644348).

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. So basically your type casting here?

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. Very informative indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
NSString *tmplabel = [tmp description];
temp.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat: @"%.f", [tmplabel doubleValue]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSString *tmplabel = [tmp description];
float tmp = [tmplabel floatValue];
temp.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat: @"%.1f", tmp];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
temp.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat: @"%.1f", tmplabel];
}
```

You can change the number infront of f to specify the accuracy.